# SQL Server syntax issue in WHERE EXISTS clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am having issues getting the below query to work that runs fine under the `UPDATE` command, but not when I am just trying to perform an equivalent `SELECT` on the data. I am getting a "syntax error" on the `WHERE EXISTS` segment. I tried modifying the `WHERE EXISTS` to include `AND` preceding it, but then I get another syntax error :

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Original SQL `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5 
SET QTY_WIP_BASE = (SELECT A.QTY 
                    FROM PS_WIP_QTY_INV_VW A 
                    WHERE A.BUSINESS_UNIT = PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5.BUSINESS_UNIT_IN 
                      AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5.INV_ITEM_ID 
                      AND PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5.INCL_WIP_QTY_FLG = 'Y' 
                      AND PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5.BUSINESS_UNIT_IN = '82DDR' 
                      AND PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5.PROCESS_INSTANCE = '8193747')    
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'X' 
               FROM PS_WIP_QTY_INV_VW A 
               WHERE A.BUSINESS_UNIT = PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5.BUSINESS_UNIT_IN 
                 AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5.INV_ITEM_ID 
                 AND PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5.INCL_WIP_QTY_FLG = 'Y' 
                 AND PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5.BUSINESS_UNIT_IN = '82DDR' 
                 AND PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5.PROCESS_INSTANCE = '8193747')
```

Modified `SELECT` query (getting syntax error):

```
SELECT 
    A.QTY 
FROM
    PS_WIP_QTY_INV_VW A, PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5 
WHERE 
    A.BUSINESS_UNIT = PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5.BUSINESS_UNIT_IN 
    AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5.INV_ITEM_ID 
    AND PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5.INCL_WIP_QTY_FLG = 'Y' 
    AND PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5.BUSINESS_UNIT_IN = '82DDR' 
    AND PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5.PROCESS_INSTANCE = '8193747' 
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 'X' 
            FROM PS_WIP_QTY_INV_VW A, PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5 
            WHERE A.BUSINESS_UNIT = PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5.BUSINESS_UNIT_IN 
              AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5.INV_ITEM_ID 
              AND PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5.INCL_WIP_QTY_FLG = 'Y' 
              AND PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5.BUSINESS_UNIT_IN = '82DDR' 
              AND PS_RPLN_MSTR_TAO5.PROCESS_INSTANCE = '8193747')
```

Comment: just get rid of the 2nd `Where` before `Exists`, so the Outer query will be `SELECT..FROM..WHERE ... And EXISTS....`, to be precise :)

Comment: Thank you very much! So logically EXISTS is the same as WHERE EXISTS? Or is the original WHERE statement being picked up where I reference EXISTS?

Comment: Pretty much, you just need ONE `WHERE` to group all the predicates ;), and that is just the syntax issue